# Color Bar Graph in xcharts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, xcharts

Has anyone changed the colors of the bar graph in xcharts?  Any idea how to do so?

The plain navy blue is so boring:

http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts/examples/

Thanks,

Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts/docs/) it does not appear the library has built in methods for styling the chart, but rather:

> The best way to style charts is to start with the included stylesheet,
>   or use your browser's element inspector to see each elements CSS class
>   selectors that are available to use.

Each series has a class: `.color0` through `.colorN`, so you could use the css to set the properties of each rectangle:

```js
var data = {
  "xScale": "ordinal",
  "yScale": "linear",
  "main": [
    {
      "className": ".pizza",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": "Pepperoni",
          "y": 4
        },
        {
          "x": "Cheese",
          "y": 8
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
var myChart = new xChart('bar', data, '#chart');
```

```css
.color0 rect {
  fill: orange !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xcharts/0.3.0/xcharts.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xcharts/0.3.0/xcharts.css">

<figure style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" id="chart"></figure>
```

Alternatively, you could use a d3 selection to alter the colors:

`d3.selectAll(".color0").selectAll("rect").style("fill","orange");`

```js
var data = {
  "xScale": "ordinal",
  "yScale": "linear",
  "main": [
    {
      "className": ".pizza",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": "Pepperoni",
          "y": 4
        },
        {
          "x": "Cheese",
          "y": 8
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
var myChart = new xChart('bar', data, '#chart');

d3.selectAll(".color0").selectAll("rect").style("fill","orange");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xcharts/0.3.0/xcharts.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xcharts/0.3.0/xcharts.css">

<figure style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" id="chart"></figure>
```

If you just want all rectangles to be a certain color, then `d3.selectAll("rect").style("fill","color")` will work.

Answer (score 1):

In Xchart we can add color of the bar using seriesColors method.

```
CategoryChart chart = new CategoryChartBuilder()
            .yAxisTitle("ABC Title")
            .theme(Styler.ChartTheme.GGPlot2).build();

    chart.getStyler().setSeriesColors(new Color[]{Color.blue, Color.cyan, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, new Color(224,43,54), new Color(24,43,124)});
```